# Are the effects of Lucio's secondary fire diminished or increased for certain heroes?

Tags: overwatch

Do heroes of different classes get affected by Lucio's Soundwave in different ways? Will a tank be pushed back less than a lightweight character?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Voting to reopen. I think there's potential for a more detailed answer, i.e. who flies how far, which wouldn't necessarily fit in the other question.

Comment: Anecdotally, I seem to remember Road Hogs not flying very far compared to Tracers, for instance.

Comment: @DCShannon at least I have been able to knock him far enough to not one shot me when he was a little slow on the trigger after hooking me.

Comment: @Dragonrage Yeah, that definitely works.

Comment: Does anyone (ideally in Europe) feel like testing this?

Comment: @Studoku I'm on EU(PC), and plan to test this again with proper recording when I get back from work. What platform are you on?

Comment: @KizTrap Also PC. Studoku#2544 if you want to add me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

[Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270153/what-are-the-weights-of-the-different-heroes-in-overwatch-and-which-abilities?rq=1)

In my testing I hit every character with concussive blast on Pharah, and each traveled approximately the same distance. I also tested knocking back Roadhog, Tracer, Zenyatta and Reinhardt with Lucio's knockback, with the same results. The knockback from Blast of Sound is agnostic of character 'weight', or distance from Lucio. If you're in the area of effect, you get knocked back X units.

One small caveat to this is Lucio himself- he traveled further than any other character. However, this is not weight related. When knocked back, Lucio traveled the same distance before making contact with the ground, but his skating shoes carried him further back, as they preserved the momentum from the blast.

Testing information:

I conducted this test in King's Row, with the Defender being the class to knockback (Pharah and Lucio), and the Attacker being the class to get knocked back. To the left of the Attacking spawn (from Attacker's PoV), there is a manhole cover near a phone booth. The defender stood on the manhole, with a spray placed the same distance as the phone booth for the Attacker to stand on.  The knockback direction went horizontally across the Attacking spawn. This ground provided a long, flat surface with no ceiling in order to keep the knockback as unaffected as possible.

Comment: Looking back, I can still do more testing on this- I have a niggling sensation that, as Lucio retains momentum post-Blast, that momentum pre-Blast may affect the knockback distance. Science to follow.

Comment: Please science for us.

Comment: This is some fantastic in-depth research. I asked this question mostly because I will notice sometimes that a heavy character like Roadhog or Reinhardt will not be pushed very far at all. As far as your testing shows, the distance an enemy is pushed is the same when hit from point blank to the end of the Soundwave blast?

Comment: My testing was with Pharah's Concussive Blast primarily, though I saw no noticeable difference with Lucio when testing proximity to target when blasting. As usual- .gifs to follow, soon as I can launch Overwatch later :)

Comment: Okay, I think this answer does the question justice. You've done your research and clearly presented it!

Comment: This is inconsistent with my play experience. I've been watching this since I first saw this question, and there have been *many* times I tried to blast a Reinhardt and got nothing.

Comment: Did he have his shield up, was he definitely in range, was he moving? My tests showed a very clear distance similarity among all classes, but they were stationary. I never tested if forward momentum cancels out part of the knockback strength

Comment: @DCShannon My guess is you blasted his shield. His shield can block the knockback and even other effects like an enemy Reinhardt's ultimate.

Comment: @NathanK That's possible. I believe I've had similar issues with the other large tanks, though. Definitely Reinhardt.

Comment: I just want to clarify on this: on the full range of Lucio's sound blast, no matter where you are in it, you will be pushed back the same distance? It appears to be really inconsistent, especially after the most recent patches. Sometimes they go flying, sometimes they move a little, sometimes not at all.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf not checked with the most recent patches if there have been changes of this nature, but the inconsistencies you can see are likely related to target momentum before blasting. At a rough guess, getting hit by the sound blast assigns a chunk of movespeed to the opposite vector you're shooting them from. So a target running towards you gets a little knockback, but a target running away gets a huge one.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer is correct, it's somehow "incomplete". Yes classes do not passively react differently to Lucio's knockback, BUT some class ability CAN alter the knockback distance.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4o4cw2/lucios_knockback_is_affected_by_certain_crowd/

A good example is D.Va, it get pushed far less while she's shooting.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, I had my suspicions with D.Va's self inflicted slow. Does that mean it's also worth testing knockbacks on targets affected by Lucio's speed aura (boosted), or Ana's Nano Boost?

Comment: Sure it's worth testing, there doesn't seem to be a general rule but I play Lucio a lot and really the effect of the knockback seems very inconsistent to me.

Comment: Totally understandable, I get the same with Pharah when playing vs players. I have also noticed Reapers using Wraith Form to suddenly cancel any momentum and move back to safety after I knock them back. So many mechanics are left unexplained!