# What are the "weights" of the different Heroes in Overwatch, and which abilities are impacted by this attribute?

Tags: overwatch

Questions pertaining to Lucio's Soundwave ability have brought up the idea that "heavier" characters are impacted by certain abilities less than "lighter" characters.  Is there data on what these weight values are?

If no data exists, is anyone able to determine at least a ranking?  Is it simply proportional to maximum health, or perhaps even a function of current health?

What other abilities are impacted by character weight?  For example, does Reinhardt's charge have less travel time after pinning a heavier character?  Do Concussion Mine or Concussive Rocket take this into account?  Does Mei take longer to freeze a heavier target?

Comment: Mei freeze time is always 1.5 seconds I'm sure, regardless of other factors.

Comment: @DeclanCarroll Correct- 1.5 seconds is the guaranteed freeze time if every tick hits. (75 total damage dealt). This is not increased by Mercy's boost or Zenyatta's Orb of Discord.

Answer (score 3):

After some testing (my plays.tv didn't record because I had two clients open simultaneously), it appears as though character weight does **NOT** affect the knockback of at least Pharah's Concussive Blast.

I tested every character vs Pharah, every single character (exceptions below) are equally affected by the knockback, regardless of character model. This includes Primal Rage Winston and Tank Configuration Bastion.

The following characters are *not* affected by knockbacks under the noted circumstances:

- Mei (Ice Block)
- Bastion (Sentry configuration). He can still be broken out of Sentry configuration via stuns (Roadghog's Chain Hook, Reinhardt's Charge)
- Reinhardt (Shielding)

I can re-record these segments at a later date if video (or gif) evidence is required for the answer, then update accordingly.

!!SCIENCE!!

Testing information:

I conducted this test in King's Row, with the Defender being the class to knockback (Pharah and Lucio), and the Attacker being the class to get knocked back. To the left of the Attacking spawn (from Attacker's PoV), there is a manhole cover near a phone booth. The defender stood on the manhole, with a spray placed the same distance as the phone booth for the Attacker to stand on. The knockback direction went horizontally across the Attacking spawn. This ground provided a long, flat surface with no ceiling in order to keep the knockback as unaffected as possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure D.Va's weight won't stay the same after she uses her Ultimate. Might want to keep that in mind when you're doing the science. Also, might be nice to know if Bastion's weight changes in Tank mode or not. Another interesting thing would be if you could check whether frozen characters are mobile or not (and if they are, whether their weight changes).

Comment: I was just about to type the same thing. D.VA off mech goes into the Light group

Comment: Good point, will update

Comment: Configuration: Sentry doesn't render Bastion immovable. Roadhog can still hook him and pull him put of Sentry. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: By immovable I mean by the function mentioned in the OP- i.e. knockback. While Bastion can still be stunned out of his Sentry mode with Roadhog's hook and Reinhardt's charge, both of those mechanics are classed as stun, not knockback.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort here.  It's difficult for me to conduct this sort of testing on console; I'm now wondering if we shouldn't verify this notion of weight altogether - it originated in an answer regarding Lucio's knock back ability, so using Tracer and Reinhardt as reference cases it would probably be worthwhile to see if there's a difference in distance there at all.  If so, it would mean this mechanic exists but does not affect all knock backs, which would be interesting...

Comment: From sight alone, I can say there was no discernable difference in knockback distance* across the board as a whole- including characters like Roadhog. I'll get some .gifs together tonight of 2 "light" characters (Tracer/Zenyatta), 2 "medium" characters (Pharah/Torbjorn) and 2 "heavy" characters (Roadhog/Reinhardt), then post them on this answer.

*excluding error margins from placement and orientation of the blast across both character tests- I was exact as I could be, but not spot on.